# Is there a way to hack display:table to make the table element values submit as input elements?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag

Is there a way to make `<display:table>` to make the table element values submit as input elements in my Struts 2 application using JSP's and the Display Tag library?

So, given ...

```
<form ... >
    <display:table uid="list"
       <display:column property="someProperty" title="title"/>
    </display:table>
</form>
```

... I want `list.someProperty` available on the Value Stack after a form submit.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of display tag columns](http://www.displaytag.org/10/tagreference-displaytag-12.html#column), you need to remove the property attribute and give the column a body and you can put whatever you want in there.

```
<form ... >
    <display:table uid="list"
       <display:column title="title">
           <input ...>...</input>
       </display:column>
    </display:table>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure how I missed that.  So obvious.  Thanks!